# Statistics: what is this property called?

Tags: statistics

For events A and B:

AB = BA

P(AB) = P(BA)

P(A)P(B) = P(B)P(A)

You can flip them.

Comment: This is not specific to statistics, but the ability to swap the order of multiplication (or any operation in general) is called _commutative_. In statistics, I am not too sure what the product of two events really means, so I can't comment on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first statement is just a basic fact of set theory: the intersection of two sets is *symmetric*. Symbolically,

$$A\cap B=B\cap A$$

Your second statement follows immediately.

Your third statement is just a consequence of the fact that probabilities are real numbers, and multiplication of real numbers is *commutative*: $ab=ba$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

Comment: The first property can also be seen as an instance of commutativity: namely, the commutativity of the *meet* (conjunction) operation in Boolean algebras.